# Omnibus package name is always blah-version-1.distro.arch.rpm, what is the "-1"?

Tags: rpm

Omnibus package name is always blah-version-1.distro.arch.rpm, what is the "-1" ?

how can I remove it?
should I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

That is called the *release* number.  It is used in conjunction with the version for determining if a given package is "newer" than what is currently installed.

The convention for *release* varies (according to who packages things).  Most just use a sequence number, corresponding to the packager's successive releases of a package.  Both *version* and *release* can include alpha/numerics and some punctuation.  I have used timestamps such as `20160406.1625` (the current local date and time) as either field.  Some use a git hash code.  It depends on who (packages) and why (their own programs, repackaging, etc).

Further information:

- [Packaging:NamingGuidelines](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:NamingGuidelines)
- [What do all the letters and numbers in a Red Hat RPM version number mean e.g. openssl-devel-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.1?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128689/what-do-all-the-letters-and-numbers-in-a-red-hat-rpm-version-number-mean-e-g-op)

Comment: I use omnibus and use the following git tag:
majorversion.minorversion.patch.m{milestone}.b{buildnumber}
is there a convention for setting the release number ?